# Http Basic Authentication using Laravel Curl Library

Tags: php, laravel, curl, basic-authentication

I am using https://github.com/ixudra/curl as a Curl library for Laravel does anyone know how to run the below command through the Curl Library;

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

I need to curl a url using HTTP basic authentication and cant seem to complete using this library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your post is quite old, but I was looking for exactly the same thing. 
You have to use the method withOption :

```
 $response = Curl::to('https://your-url.com')
                       ->withOption('USERPWD', 'user:password')
                       ->post();
```

If you want to use any other curl option, you have to remove the prefix "CURLOPT_".